# When I compile boost 1.48\1.47 code with C++11 compatible compiler do I end up with std implementation of stuff like share_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++11, std

When I compile boost 1.48\1.47 code with C++11 compatible compiler do I end up with std implementation of stuff like share_ptr, threads etc? If not what are boost views on that, will it ever compile when possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will end up with the boost implementation of those components. The interfaces are quite similar to the standard versions, but not always identical.

Comment: The interfaces are not as important as implementations... Which some guys (ex MSVC) some times do more platform/compiler optimezed. So if I say use interfaces that are boost only - I get it - boost implementation is required, but when I use some component same way as I would in std... rabl-rabl, bla-bla-bla=)